# graphics.drawline makes line to lare

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I am a novice in C# (following night school) and am experimenting with some stuff (haven't seen it yet in class).

I am trying to build a palletizing tool, which displays the optimal way to pallatize boxes on a pallet.
Before coding the alorithm to do so I was looking into how I could display the pallet.

My eye caught the Graphics.Drawline method in combination with an override of the OnPaint methode and I have no trouble drawing the line, but it is always to large!

For testing I set my form to 500*500 and I want a line of 500pxl. I would asume if I resize the window that I would immediatly see the end of the line, but it still goes on for about 5-7pxl.

Is there a difference in metrics or something? Below an example of the code I use.

Thanks for any help, couldn't find any related topics on the web that would explain this (perhaps it's just that obvious...).

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs paintEvnt)
    {
        // Get the graphics object 
        Graphics gfx = paintEvnt.Graphics;
        // Create a new pen that we shall use for drawing the line 
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        // draw pallet
        //lenght1
        gfx.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 50, 500, 50);
       //width1
        gfx.DrawLine(myPen, 500, 50, 500, 100);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely being caused by the window you're drawing this in. If you look around the edges of a windows form popup (assuming you're using a windows forms application) you'll see a border.

This border is included in the width of the window. That's why the line seems to go on for a little bit past the edge of your window - you can't see the actual end of the line until you stretch the window and move its border.